# 400 Bad Request "Forbidden"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou a testar o Jasmin através da versão demo e já criei a aplicação e correspondente subscrição no nitrogen.

Através dos exemplos do Postman do repositório Github, já consigo obter o access token "client credentials".

Mas, ao tentar utilizar outros endpoints como, por exemplo, o `/billing/invoices` disponível também nos Postman samples, recebo sempre um 400 Bad Request com message: "Forbidden".

Estou a usar o Authorization em forma de Bearer Token.

Aqui vai o body:

```
GET /api/xxxxxx/xxxxxx-yyyy/billing/invoices HTTP/1.1
Host: my.jasminsoftware.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Bearer zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d0c5a19c-5448-4c19-b565-f09d80b7b883,3b40913b-1254-4e82-9370-4a9d0e49974d
Host: my.jasminsoftware.com
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

O que poderá estar errado ou a faltar?

A aplicação que estamos a tentar integrar está na plataforma Ruby on Rails. Aqui vai o código que estava a tentar usar para testar (usando a gem rest-client https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client):

```
require "rest-client"

auth_url = "https://identity.primaverabss.com/core/connect/token"
grant_type = "client_credentials"
scope= "application"
client_id = <CLIENT_ID>
client_secret = <CLIENT_SECRET>
account = <ACCOUNT>
subscription = <SUBSCRIPTION>

response = RestClient.post(auth_url, {grant_type: grant_type, scope: scope, client_id: client_id, client_secret: client_secret})
access_token = JSON.parse(response.body)["access_token"]

host = "https://my.jasminsoftware.com/api" 
endpoint = "billing/invoices"
url = "#{host}/#{account}/#{subscription}/#{endpoint}"

request = RestClient::Request.new(method: :get, url: url, headers: {authorization: "Bearer #{access_token}", accept: "application/json"})
response = request.execute
```

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo do codigo?

Comment: Ainda não tenho código nenhum. Apenas estou a tentar avaliar a API através do Postman. O problema que estou a ter aparenta ser exatamente o mesmo que este: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397524/400-bad-request-message-forbidden. No dia da publicação do mesmo, apareceu um comentário que dizia que havia um bug e que estaria a ser resolvido, mas esse comentário desapareceu. Mas ainda não consigo fazer nada com a API para além da obtenção do Token.

Comment: Pode então facultar os headers e os scopes que está a pedir?

Comment: Adicionei a pergunta com o código Ruby que estava a testar agora. Continuo a receber um `400 Bad Request`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de ver o vídeo [aqui](https://developers.primaverabss.com/jasmin/?cat=videos-2) percebi que me faltava um passo antes de fazer a primeira chamada à API que é o de ligar a aplicação à subscrição do Jasmin aqui: https://apps.primaverabss.com.

Depois disto, o código Ruby que aqui expus funciona como esperado.

Obrigado e espero que esta informação ajude outros novatos, como é o meu caso.